# admin on rest in create form - Generated the TextInput by loop. If I type anything in one text-box, it is reflecting in all other generated text-box

Tags: admin-on-rest

I created the TextInput by loop. If I type anything in one text-box, it is reflecting in all other textbox's as well. How to prevent this reflecting one textbox value into others textbox's automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should set it's `source` property. But it's always best to show an example of your problem in a codesandbox.